# How to layout the flux grid view in the backend?

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

I'm using flux (7.0.0) and fluidcontent (4.0.0) on TYPO3 6.2. My content model is as follows, using the "Composite Pattern":

- There is a content element "row" (in different flavors), which is a container element, to contain more content elements. It has only one subcolumn of content.
- There are "leaf" content elements, to display the actual content. Examples would be "single image", "text", but also "row". Each of these leafs has a `width` as property.

The whole thing is rendered for bootstrap, and within each row, the children are just floated left.

My question is: How do I layout the content elements in the backend grid view to resemble the frontend output? It would be a great improvement if each content element would get a display-width added from its properties and be floated left.

The grid definition in the content element looks like this:

```
<flux:flexform.grid>
    <flux:flexform.grid.row>
        <flux:flexform.content name="rowcontent" label="{f:translate(id: 'row.column.label')}" />
    </flux:flexform.grid.row>
</flux:flexform.grid>
```

An example of the current layout in the backend. Each of the image content elements has 25% width set to it. It would be much nicer, if they would be beside each other:

[image: Current layout in the backend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the preview section of your template you would normally use `<flux:widget.grid />`.

Instead:

1) Copy over the files from `flux / Resources / Private / Templates / ViewHelpers / Widget / Grid /` and  `flux / Classes / ViewHelpers / Widget /` to your extension.

2) Rename inside everything you copied to fit your vendor prefix / namespace.

3) Include that new namespace inside your row template and use `<YourNamespace:widget.grid />` for the preview.

4) Now you can customize the templates you copied over so that they are floated instead of in a table.

Comment: This works. One addition though:

There is no need to copy the ViewHelper, it suffices to set `plugin.tx_flux.view.templateRootPath = EXT:extkey/…`. That eliminates the need to manually update the copied Viewhelper when updating (but has other drawbacks, e.g. if another template is added to flux).

Comment: I'll wait some more days, and if no better answer pops up, you'll get the bounty.

Comment: Hey Jost, sure you can override the templates. I explicitly opted out of suggesting that because you want to overlay just that one and keep the flexibility.